# Cocos2d-x: How to replace sprite dynamically?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am struggling to replace the sprite I selected to another sprite.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
void Object::replaceSprite(const string & resourceName)
{
    cocos2d::SpriteFrameCache * spriteFrameCache = cocos2d::SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
    cocos2d::SpriteFrame * spriteFrame = spriteFrameCache->getSpriteFrameByName(resourceName);

    //mSprite->setTexture(spriteFrame->getTexture());
    //mSprite->setDisplayFrame(spriteFrame);
    mSprite->setSpriteFrame(resourceName);

}
```

As you can see, I tried different approach but none of them worked.

Also, I would like to ask if I do have to add the sprite again once I replace the frame onto the scene? What I am thinking right now is to create a new sprite every time I asked to replace it with a new one. But I do not know if there is more elegant and efficient way to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

setSpriteFrame accept a string or SpriteFrame* as argument

in your code

> mSprite->setSpriteFrame(resourceName);

the argument is a string, you have no need to get frame from frameCache, but you must make sure that the frame exists in frameCache.

you can make breakpoint in the function, and check if spriteFrame is nullptr after

> cocos2d::SpriteFrame * spriteFrame = spriteFrameCache->getSpriteFrameByName(resourceName);

Comment: That's what I did as well moments ago. Actually I checked the spriteFrame on the debugger and noticed that the _textureFilename is empty.

Comment: Have you noticed I commented those lines? It means I have tried them, none of them worked. I also tried you code. It didn't work as well.

Comment: @Neon Warge just use mSprite->setSpriteFrame(resourceName); there is no problem in this code, if not work, the problem is you haven't added the frame into frameCache.

Comment: That's impossible, I added a fake resource name it crashes. So it means it should crash if it couldn't find it, but it isn't crashing, therefore, it is loaded. I also check the spriteFrameCache and the resourceName I am looking is there.